# How to populate notification in a TextView?

Tags: android

i'm working in a notification app Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM) , and i would like to populate in a `TextView` the notifications i received in a new activity, when i clicked in the notification, the activity is showing , but without the notification message 
any help please 
this is my code

```
private void enviarNotificacion(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
String title = data.get("title");
String body = data.get("body");

NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "Acc";


Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.putExtra("title", title);
intent.putExtra("body", body);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = endingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
builder.setAutoCancel(true)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setTicker("Acc ")
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(body)
        .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000})
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setContentInfo("info");
manager.notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

and my main_where i want to populate the notification

```
txtTitulo=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.titulotxt);
txtNotificacion=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNotificacion);

Intent bundle= getIntent();
if (bundle != null) {
    Titulo = bundle.getStringExtra("title");
    MensajeNotificacion = bundle.getStringExtra("body");
    txtTitulo.setText(Titulo);
    txtNotificacion.setText(MensajeNotificacion);

  }
```

Comment: Intent bundle= getIntent(); ... is bundle null?

Comment: thats my problem my bundle is always null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    intent.putExtra("body", body);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

try this for your intent/pending intent